# In MVC, why doesn't HandleError or Application_Error catch SqlExceptions?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

In MVC, why doesn't HandleError (extended or not) or Application_Error catch SqlExceptions?

```
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        int httpcode = new HttpException(null, filterContext.Exception).GetHttpCode();

        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled || !filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
            return;
        if (!ExceptionType.IsInstanceOfType(filterContext.Exception))
            return;

        var er = new OEB.DataAccess.ErrorHandlerRepository();
        er.LogException("Custom - " + filterContext.Exception.ToString());

        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        switch (httpcode)
        {
            case 404:
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/ErrorHandler/NotFound");
                break;
            case 500:
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/ErrorHandler/ServerError");
                break;
            default:
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/ErrorHandler/General");
                break;
        }            
    }
```

I register this in Filter.Config:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new CustomErrorHandlerAttribute());
    }
}
```

I am using Dapper, and trying to catch the SQLException from an invalid insert(AspNetRoles2 does not exist), and get the normal yellow screen:

```
    public bool CreateRole(string roleName)
    {
        int rowsAffected = Execute("INSERT into AspNetRoles2 (RoleName) VALUES (@roleName)", new { roleName = roleName });
        return rowsAffected == 1 ? true : false;
    }

    protected int Execute(string sp, object parameters = null)
    {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(secConnStr))
                {
                    rowsAffectedCount = conn.Execute(sp, parameters);
                }
                scope.Complete();
            }
     }
```

Comment: It will handle SqlException's. Perhaps you should provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And no, HandleError doesn't replace the need for try/catch. They're used for different things.

Comment: Thanks mason, I added more information.

Comment: I see what you mean, try / catch is used in the same way as in web forms, and I'll add in the normal way,  but HandleError is to catch unhandled errors before the yellow screen of death. I'm still not sure why my forced SQL error is not caught.